# Dynamic Toggle Div Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it where if you click on a button in the side bar it shows/slides up some text in the content section on the right of the sidebar. I would also like to toggle this by clicking the button (if that makes sense).

Any help would be really appreciated.

This is what I have so far: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fymjqonc/4/

```js
$(function($) {
  $('.show').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('toggle')).show();
  });
  $('[data-toggle="item1"]').click();
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.nav {
  background: lightgrey;
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="show" data-toggle="item1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show" data-toggle="item2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show" data-toggle="item3">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show" data-toggle="item4">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show" data-toggle="item5">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="toggle" id="item1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni rerum repellat sed quo eum consequuntur aliquid nobis dolore tempore. Enim.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle" id="item2">
      <p>Step 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle" id="item3">
      <p>Step 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle" id="item4">
      <p>Step 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle" id="item5">
      <p>Step 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Sorry but i don't really understand what you want to do, but take look of this snippet code for the highlighted menu.

```js
$(function($) {
  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
   let index = $('nav ul li').index(this) + 1,
      list = $('nav ul li');
    
    list.removeClass('active');
    $('.content div').slideUp();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.content div:nth-child('+ index +')').slideDown();
   
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.nav {
  background: lightgrey;
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}

.content > div  {
  display: none;
}

.content > div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >Step 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >Step 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"  >Step 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"  >Step 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"  >Step 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni rerum repellat sed quo eum consequuntur aliquid nobis dolore tempore. Enim.</p>
    </div>
    <div >
      <p>Step 2</p>
    </div>
    <div >
      <p>Step 3</p>
    </div>
    <div >
      <p>Step 4</p>
    </div>
    <div >
      <p>Step 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for not explaining myself as clear as possible. I believe you have pretty much done what I was looking for.

I have a final question: is there a way for me to loop through the sidebar? For example, if I click on item 5 in the sidebar, and then click item 1, is there a way to make it scroll through all items before it gets to item 1? I'm assuming that would be some sort of CSS transition?

Thank you for your help btw!

Comment: Ok, take look of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) you should use a jQuery scrollTo. Or you can make your own function or you can use a plugin like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-scrollTo#table-of-contents)